# Not able to get firebase datasnapshot value string

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nullpointerexception

[This is the structure of my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mgr2c.png)This is the code to get the user_name from the database
The (dataSnapshot)shows Not Annotated parameter overrides @NonNull parameter
I have added the whole code for the settingsActivity down below i hope this helps

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private CircleImageView settingsDisplayProfileImage;
    private TextView settingsDisplayname;
    private TextView settingsDisplayStatus;
    private TextView settingsDisplayaddress;
    private TextView settingsDisplayphone;
    private TextView settingsDisplayservice;
    private Button settingsChangeProfileImageButton;
    private Button settingsUpdateProfileButton;


    private final static int Gallery_Pick = 1;
    private StorageReference storeProfileImagestorageRef;


    private DatabaseReference getUserDataReference;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    Bitmap thumb_bitmap = null;

    private StorageReference thumbImageRef;
    private ProgressDialog loadingBar;
    private String downloadImageUrl;
    private String online_user_id;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        online_user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        getUserDataReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(online_user_id);
        getUserDataReference.keepSynced(true);


        storeProfileImagestorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Profile_Images");

        thumbImageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Thumb_Images");

        settingsDisplayProfileImage = (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.settings_profile_image);
        settingsDisplayname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.settings_username);
        settingsDisplayaddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.settings_user_address);
        settingsDisplayphone = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.settings_user_phone);
        settingsDisplayservice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.settings_user_service);
        settingsDisplayStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.settings_user_status);
        settingsChangeProfileImageButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.settings_change_profile_image_button);
        settingsUpdateProfileButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.settings_update_profile);
        loadingBar= new ProgressDialog(this);

        getUserDataReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if (dataSnapshot.exists())
                {
                //error occurs here first line below
                String name = dataSnapshot.child("user_name").getValue().toString();
                String status = dataSnapshot.child("user_status").getValue().toString();
                final String image = dataSnapshot.child("user_image").getValue().toString();
                String address = dataSnapshot.child("user_address").getValue().toString();
                String phone = dataSnapshot.child("user_phone").getValue().toString();
                String service = dataSnapshot.child("user_service").getValue().toString();
                String thumb_image = dataSnapshot.child("user_thumb_image").getValue().toString();


                settingsDisplayname.setText(name);
                settingsDisplayservice.setText(service);
                settingsDisplayStatus.setText(status);
                settingsDisplayaddress.setText(address);
                settingsDisplayphone.setText(phone);

                if (!image.equals("default_profile")) {
                    //
```

this is the other half of the code but everything from here works fine...

```
Picasso.with(SettingsActivity.this).load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.default_profile).into(settingsDisplayProfileImage);

                        Picasso.with(SettingsActivity.this).load(image).fit().centerInside().networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
                                .placeholder(R.drawable.default_profile).into(settingsDisplayProfileImage, new Callback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess() {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError() {
                                Picasso.with(SettingsActivity.this).load(image).fit().centerInside().placeholder(R.drawable.default_profile).into(settingsDisplayProfileImage);
                            }
                        });
                    }

                }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });


            settingsChangeProfileImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
                    galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, Gallery_Pick);
                }
            });


            settingsUpdateProfileButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    String old_status = settingsDisplayStatus.getText().toString();
                    String old_address = settingsDisplayaddress.getText().toString();
                    String old_phone = settingsDisplayphone.getText().toString();
                    String old_service = settingsDisplayservice.getText().toString();

                    Intent profileIntent = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                    profileIntent.putExtra("user_status", old_status);
                    profileIntent.putExtra("user_service", old_service);
                    profileIntent.putExtra("user_phone", old_phone);
                    profileIntent.putExtra("user_address", old_address);
                    startActivity(profileIntent);
                }
            });

        }


        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if(requestCode==Gallery_Pick && resultCode==RESULT_OK &&data!=null)
            {
                Uri ImageUri = data.getData();

                CropImage.activity()
                        .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                        .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                        .start(this);

            }

            if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE)
            {
                CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);

                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
                {
                    loadingBar.setTitle("Updating Profile Image");
                    loadingBar.setMessage("Please wait while profile image is updated");
                    loadingBar.show();

                    Uri resultUri = result.getUri();


                    File thumb_filepathUri = new File(resultUri.getPath());



                    String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();


                    try
                    {
                        thumb_bitmap = new Compressor(this)
                                .setMaxWidth(100)
                                .setMaxHeight(100)
                                .setQuality(50)
                                .compressToBitmap(thumb_filepathUri);
                    }
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    thumb_bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, byteArrayOutputStream);
                    final byte[] thumb_byte = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();



                    StorageReference filePath = storeProfileImagestorageRef.child(user_id + ".jpg");

                    final StorageReference thumb_filePath = thumbImageRef.child(user_id + ".jpg");





                    filePath.putFile(resultUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull final Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task)
                        {
                            if (task.isSuccessful())
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this,
                                        "Saving profile image...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                             //   final String downloadUrl = task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString();
                                downloadImageUrl =thumb_filePath .getDownloadUrl().toString();

                                UploadTask uploadTask = thumb_filePath.putBytes(thumb_byte);

                                uploadTask.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>()
                                {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>thumb_task)
                                    {
                                        String thumb_downloadUrl = thumb_filePath.getDownloadUrl().toString();
                                     //  thumb_downloadImageUrl = filePath.getDownloadUrl().toString();
                                        if (task.isSuccessful())
                                        {
                                            Map update_user_data = new HashMap();
                                            update_user_data.put("user_image", downloadImageUrl);
                                            update_user_data.put("user_thumb_image", thumb_downloadUrl);

                                            getUserDataReference.updateChildren(update_user_data)
                                                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>()
                                                    {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)
                                                        {
                                                            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this,
                                                                    "Profile Image Updated Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                                            loadingBar.dismiss();

                                                        }
                                                    });
                                        }

                                    }
                                });



                            }

                            else
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Error occurred while uploading your profile picture..",
                                                                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                loadingBar.dismiss();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }

                else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
                    Exception error = result.getError();
                }
            }


        }
    }
```

this is the logcat below

```
11-15 03:22:10.646 27837-27837/com.paddi.paddi.paddi E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.paddi.paddi.paddi, PID: 27837
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
        at com.paddi.paddi.paddi.SettingsActivity$1.onDataChange(SettingsActivity.java:101)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5765)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

Comment: It seems the `getValue()` returned `null`.

Comment: Ideally, you should be using a single call of something like `getValue(User.class)`, where this class maps to your Database entity

Comment: @cricket_007 I wouldn't necessarily call that "ideal" as there are reasons why you might not want to do that.  1) It uses reflection, which can be slow (especially for large records), 2) you may only really need a subset of the fields, and 2) the data may not already be in the format you want.

Comment: In any case, please [edit] your question to include a screenshot or JSON export of the reference being queried. And show how `getUserDataReference` gets defined

Comment: Please post your JSON structure and code that describes `getUserDataReference`.

Comment: What is `getUserDataReference`?

Comment: What is the value of `getUserDataReference`? Please responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo i  am trying to get the user_name from the reference

Comment: @JohnEnokela If you are trying to get the user_name, please also post your database structure.

Comment: @AlexMamo i have added a screenshot of the database structure above

Comment: Have you tried to use `dataSnapshot.child("user_name").getValue(String.class);` instead of `dataSnapshot.child("user_name").getValue().toString();`? What is the result?

Comment: @AlexMamo Thank you so much it works now, i hope to get more assistance from you when i run into any more bugs

Comment: That's no problem. Just ask a question and if I'm here, I'll provide you assistance.

Comment: i cant seem to find the checkmark